# Remove VideoView black flash before video start

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using `VideoView` to play a video and was wondering how to remove black frame flash before video starts. I would like to remove it or set it to a color of my screen background.

This black background is also causing problem on the bottom of the video where 1px thick line appears and it's really visible on my screen's background.

There are a couple of topics about this and most of the people suggest the following solution to get triggered in `onFinishInflate()` or in constructor:

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

This approach works and there is no more first frame black flash and that black 1px line at the bottom of the `VideoView` but there is now bigger issue. If using this approach I can't set any `View` on top of the `VideoView`.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout to put another View on top of your VideoView.  When the video starts playing, hide the View.

(This assumes you're *not* using `setZOrderOnTop()`, which puts the video Surface in front of everything.)

Comment: Thank you but listening when video starts playing is not really reliable and there can still be a small black flash. Also, this doesn't solve bottom black line and black last frame which sometimes appears.